# How do I see the names of all view fields in the formatter option form?

Tags: views, 8

I am extending the StylePluginBase to make a custom views formatter. I would like to add a select box in the option menu with a list of all the fields currently listed within the view. How do I pull the list of fields into the buildOptionsForm function? Does the FormStateInterface have the view buried in it somewhere that I need to do something like:

```
$options = [];
$view = $form_state->view;
foreach($view->fields as $field){
  $options[] = $field->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but maybe still helpful for someone.
You can use `$fields = $this->displayHandler->getFieldLabels(TRUE);` to get an array of all currently chosen fields in the view.